# Desempenho do SQL ao dividir resultados em categorias

Tags: php, sql, phpmyadmin, mariadb

Tenho um banco com todos os produtos de minha loja, quero listar os produtos por categorias mas não sei qual a forma mais eficiente para isso, porque é um banco grande. Seria melhor eu buscar todos os produtos de uma vez e com `foreach` e `if` fazer os agrupamentos dos itens? Ou fazer mais de uma query e em cada busca utilizar `WHERE categoria = 'MinhaCategora'`?

Ou teria alguma outra opção para fazer esse agrupamento?

Answer (score 0):

Efectua filtro por categoria reduz ao máximo o teu resultado sob pena de retornar milhões de registos e não conseguirás colocar em memória, adicionalmente verifica se tens indexação nessa coluna da tabela "catgorias" para otimizar a tua consulta.